# Python check if an argument is a string or a list with one string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to pass to a function a string argument. But a list containing one string element is ok, too.

Is there a more compact / pythonic way to to this?

```
files = ["myfile"]
isinstance(files[0], list) and len(files[0]) == 1
```

Comment: I don't think so. However, it looks like it should be `isinstance(files, list) and len(files) == 1` instead

Comment: you can use `final_string = ' '.join(lis[0])`
also your `isinstance(files[0], list) and len(files[0]) == 1` will result in false. the correct way can be `isinstance(files[0], str) and len(files) == 1`

Comment: @ForceBru yes, you're right. In my case it returns `False`, in yours `True`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by

```
files = ["myfile"]
function(files if isinstance(files, list) and len(files) == 1 else files[0])
```

or you can change the files[0] to other element if you want a diffrent element in case files is not a list that contain 1 item.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use a `*args` parameter to avoid the check.

```
def f(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)

f('foo')
foo

f(*['foo'])
foo
```

Of course the caller must use the correct calling convention, which may or may not be problematic.

If the above approach is not feasible, and it also not feasible to redesign the application to avoid this argument overloading then `isinstance` is as good as anything.

I would check vs `str` so that containers other than `list`s are accepted by the function (such as `deque`s and `tuple`s).

```
s = files if isinstance(files, str) else files[0]
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution, but I have multiple arguments to check this way, and I cannot use `def f(*args1, *args2, *args3)`